# Data not inserting in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table named as user_data_insitutes and the values to it are passed correctly, i have debuged that the values are being passed and no empty value is passed..

here is the code

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `secure_login`.`user_data_institution` (`id`, `namecontact`, `emailinst`, `nameofinst`, `yearsofexsistance`, `contactinst`, `institutionhour`, `websiteinst`, `address`, `institutionstate`, `institutioncity`, `institutionzipcode`, `aboutinst`, `institutiosizeoffaculty`, `institutionlearninglocatiom`, `nooflocations`, `learningaddress1`, `learninglocality1`, `learningaddress2`, `learninglocality2`, `learningaddress3`, `learninglocality3`, `learningaddress4`, `learninglocality4`, `learningaddress5`, `learninglocality5`, `coursename1`, `coursefeesinstitution1`, `frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution1`, `maxstudentsinstitution1`, `courselength1`, `courselength21`, `demoinstitution1`, `lengthofclassinstitution1`, `coursename2`, `coursefeesinstitution2`, `frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution2`, `maxstudentsinstitution2`, `courselength2`, `courselength22`, `demoinstitution2`, `lengthofclassinstitution2`, `coursename3`, `coursefeesinstitution3`, `frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution3`, `maxstudentsinstitution3`, `courselength3`, `courselength23`, `demoinstitution3`, `lengthofclassinstitution3`, `coursename4`, `coursefeesinstitution4`, `frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution4`, `maxstudentsinstitution4`, `courselength4`, `courselength24`, `demoinstitution4`, `lengthofclassinstitution4`, `coursename5`, `coursefeesinstitution5`, `frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution5`, `maxstudentsinstitution5`, `courselength5`, `courselength25`, `demoinstitution5`, `lengthofclassinstitution5`, `institutiondays1`, `institutiontime1`, `institutiondays2`, `institutiontime2`, `institutiondays3`, `institutiontime3`, `institutiondays4`, `institutiontime4`, `institutiondays5`, `institutiontime5`, `locationsforlearning1`, `locationsforlearning2`, `locationsforlearning3`, `locationsforlearning4`, `locationsforlearning5`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param('i,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s',$userid,$namecontact,$emailinst,$nameofinst,$yearsofexsistance,$contactinst ,$institutionhour,$websiteinst,$address ,$institutionstate ,$institutioncity ,$institutionzipcode ,$aboutinst,$institutiosizeoffaculty,$institutionlearninglocatiom,$nooflocations,$learningaddress1,$learninglocality1,$learningaddress2,$learninglocality2,$learningaddress3,$learninglocality3,$learningaddress4,$learninglocality4,$learningaddress5,$learninglocality5,$coursename1,$coursefeesinstitution1,$frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution1,$maxstudentsinstitution1,$courselength1,$courselength21,$demoinstitution1,$lengthofclassinstitution1,$coursename2,$coursefeesinstitution2,$frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution2,$maxstudentsinstitution2,$courselength2,$courselength22,$demoinstitution2,$lengthofclassinstitution2,$coursename3,$coursefeesinstitution3,$frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution3,$maxstudentsinstitution3,$courselength3,$courselength23,$demoinstitution3,$lengthofclassinstitution3,$coursename4,$coursefeesinstitution4,$frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution4,$maxstudentsinstitution4,$courselength4,$courselength24,$demoinstitution4,$lengthofclassinstitution4,$coursename5,$coursefeesinstitution5,$frequencyoffeescollectioninstitution5,$maxstudentsinstitution5,$courselength5,$courselength25,$demoinstitution5,$lengthofclassinstitution5,$institutiondays1,$institutiontime1,$institutiondays2,$institutiontime2,$institutiondays3,$institutiontime3,$institutiondays4,$institutiontime4,$institutiondays5,$institutiontime5,$locationsforlearning1,$locationsforlearning2,$locationsforlearning3,$locationsforlearning4,$locationsforlearning5);

$stmt->execute();
```

but the statement is not executing..please help me out.

db connection are being made as the same files contains other codes that are being executed.

Comment: RTFMs http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: you dont need the commas in `$stmt->bind_param('i,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,....` just `$stmt->bind_param('isssssss....` But as above RTM its the first please to look **not the last**

Comment: Look error in your query  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thanks a lot sir..its working perfectly now!

Comment: and that's what happens when you throw out the old VCR manual to set the time correctly.

Comment: by the way, you added a PDO tag; this isn't PDO, it's mysqli - I removed it

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `bind_param` is incorrect.

You need to have one character defining the datatype of each parameter as you have but you do not add commas between each definition letter.

So you code it like this

```
$stmt->bind_param('isss',$userid,$namecontact,$emailinst,$nameofinst);
```

I shortened your code for brevity